# Typescript change type from number to actual value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can you please tell me how can I change the type from number to value in typescript react.

Please see my below code

```
const smPx = 375;
export const break = {

  xs: `@media (max-width: ${smPx - 1}px)` as const
}
```

When I Mouse over I am seeing the type as number and not as value

```
export declare const break: {

    readonly xs: `@media (max-width: ${number}px)`;
   
};
```

How can I change from number to show value.

Thanks

Comment: Ts won't do math in the type system as far as I know

Comment: I think you just need to remove `as const` and just define your type like as following: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBC2AFAHjAvDAzAdgKwG4AoAU2QAcQAnWUSWAI0uIEMBrREASzCggC4YAbxhNmAE3AAbAJ4xk-OFErcA5jAC+6IYUIw9chQAMAAvGJjOzGAAp4zZAFoA7pzFQAFgIAkghChgOMACM6mTIAJSGhOqEQA

Comment: i tried that also still while mouse over shows as number and not as the value